# Drupal: Field of View is not presented on the page that was created by this View

Tags: drupal-6, views2

I have an ImageField in my View. It is not exluded from output. It is presented in preview. But when I open the page created by the View - it is not presented there. How can I diagnose this issue ? (all caches are turned off, drupal v6, views v2)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few ideas that come to mind:

- switch to another theme, to see if a theme function is causing the problem
- view the page source, to see if the html wrapping the imagefield is there
- if the img URL is there, go to that URL directly, to see if you get an error
- clear the Views cache, which is on the Tools tab in Views

Comment: No, this does not help :( And there is no html wrapper for imagefield